# Why have some Hyperloop researchers abandoned the air bearings initial idea?

Tags: bearings, air

Air bearings are a cheap solution for Hyperloop, unlike the costly magnetic levitation system. I'm consulting some sources and it seems there's enough air in the tube at 100 Pa to feed the air bearings.

Comment: The mass flow required? Control issues?

Comment: There is enough mass flow in the tube at 100 Pa, right? 3.43 kg/s if the pod is moving at 338,89 m/s. And the compressor could admit 1.7 kg/s.