# Why can't we use air bearings for Hyperloop? Why isn't it feasible?

Tags: bearings, air

Why isn't the usage of air bearings for HL feasible?

Comment: See https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/26995/10902

Comment: Also https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/27040/10902

Comment: And https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/27014/10902

Comment: Solar Mike, I'm desperate, I can't find the info I need... It looks like air bearings are scarcely used...

Comment: what about https://www.aerogo.com/products/air-caster-rigging-system/?keyword_session_id=vt~adwords|kt~air%20bearings|mt~e|ta~310736558588&_vsrefdom=wordstream&gclid=Cj0KCQjwnpXmBRDUARIsAEo71tTOJHrV4TAs9npW05TDZjHBWmiOLatoNtJdGd9gWFabjw1WCjQCqFQaAiuxEALw_wcB

Comment: and http://www.labmotionsystems.com/product-category/products/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwnpXmBRDUARIsAEo71tSZUf5nVFr0RNUUv4Bac1n6KqYPhBDuvVteFrtNJf3nAQqP4gtC1GoaAp_QEALw_wcB